# How to detect TIME when reading from an excel sheet using R

Tags: r, openxlsx

The issue is that when I read from an excel sheet into R using `read.xlsx` from `openxlsx` package, the `TIME` column is converted into a fraction.

Here is an example,

```
dfin <-
DATE          TIME
15/02/2015    8:00 AM
22/01/2014    10:00 PM

library(openxlsx)
test <-  read.xlsx("dfin.xlsx", sheet = 1,
                 detectDates=TRUE, skipEmptyRows = TRUE,
                 skipEmptyCols = TRUE, rows = NULL, cols = NULL, check.names = FALSE,
                 namedRegion = NULL, na.strings = "NA", fillMergedCells = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
  DATE        TIME
  2015-02-15  0.3333333
  2014-01-22  0.9166667
```

I am not sure why it does that and whether there is a way to fix that as I need to use both DATE and TIME to do some calculations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

R doesn't have a time format really, so I suggest reading it in using `read_excel`, which automatically detects the column type. This will turn it into a date-time format with a random date, which you can then remove, before converting it into a proper timestamp.

```
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)

test <- read_excel('dfin.xlsx',trim_ws = TRUE) %>%
  #return the TIME column to the way it is written in Excel
  mutate(TIME = as.character(gsub(".* ","",TIME)),
  #format the date column
     DATE = dmy(DATE),
  #turn it into a timestamp
     TIMESTAMP = as.POSIXct(paste(DATE,TIME)))
```

Answer (score 5):

My first guess was that `read.xlsx()` is trying to guess the date-looking columns in .xlsx while it reads the file, and weirdly converts the time from `%I:%M %p` format into fractions of 24 hours (because e.g. `0.3333333 * 24 = 7.999999` [which is exactly 8.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...)). But latter I noticed that if I change the parameter `detectDates` into `FALSE` nothing really changes - it outputs the same data frame. So it guess nothing, it just reads the `TIME` as it is.

If you try to edit `10:00 PM` within Excel workbook, you'll see that it is really stored as `22:00:00`. So why at the end it is represented as a fraction of `24`?! I don't know, and I hope someone can explain that.

@Randall approach is really good alternative comparing to `openxlsx::read.xlsx()`. Note that `read_xlsx()` recognizes `TIME` as `%H:%M:%S`, and converts it into the dummy `POSIXct/POSIXt` object, i.e. `1899-12-31 08:00:00` and `1899-12-31 22:00:00`.

Surprisingly, `read_xlsx()` doesn't recognize that `DATE` has `%d-%m-%Y` format, and interpret it as a `character`. Meaning that we need to convert both variables into appropriate format in order to obtain desired output.

I don't think we need to use `gsub` to get the 12-hour clock time from `POSIXct` object, it is much easire to use `format` for this purpose. And conversion of `DATE` from `%d-%m-%Y` into `%Y-%m-%d` format is even an easier task:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

read_xlsx("myfile.xlsx") |>
  mutate(
    DATE = as.Date(DATE, "%d/%m/%Y"), 
    TIME = format(TIME, "%I:%M %p")   # “That’s what I do: I drink and I know things.”
 )
```

Which produces:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  DATE       TIME    
  <date>     <chr>   
1 2015-02-15 08:00 AM
2 2014-01-22 10:00 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and solved it as follows - quick and dirty:

- Read the data using `readxl:read_excel()`.
- Without loss of generality, we just look at obtaining `17:20` from `"0.72222222222222"` instead of a column containing the time data. Be aware of reading values out of an excel file could have unwanted types, but for calculations we need numerics.
- 

```
x <- as.numeric("0.72222222222222")*24 

minutes <- round((x %% 1)*60, digits = 0) 
hours <- round(x - minutes/60, digits = 0)
if (minutes < 10){ #if minutes is a single digit need to insert a preceding 0
    minutes= paste0("0",minutes)
}
paste0(hours, ":", minutes)
#17:20
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `times()` function in the chron package will give the solution:

```
library(chron)

times(0.111)
```

> `[1] 02:39:50`

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the time values as "date":

   ```
    test <- read_excel('dfin.xlsx', col_types = c("date"), ...)
   ```
2. Then trim it with `substr()` to get the time:

   ```
    test <- substr(test,12,16)
   ```